# MYSQL error reading communication packets

Tags: mysql, mariadb, litespeed

I get

> 2021-06-03 11:04:07 5559 [Warning] Aborted connection 5559 to db:
> 'mydbname' user: 'mydbusername' host: 'localhost' (Got an error
> reading communication packets)

every 10 minutes in mysql log file.
[image]

the my.cnf setting is this:

```
innodb_file_per_table = 1
max_allowed_packet = 2500M
interactive_timeout=7000
max-connections=2500
```

How can I find the problem?

Note: I'm using litespeed,MYSQL,Mariadb